# Opening a device file from a Linux device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux device driver that needs to manipulate another device driver. Specifically I need to open the device file and call `ioctl` every now and then.

I have read about `sys_open`, `sys_ioctl` etc. but I am not sure if this is the way to go. Is there a better way to do what I want to do?

If I go ahead and use `sys_open`, `sys_ioctl`, etc., how do I make sure that the driver for the device I need to open is initialised before my own device driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open + ioctl are good enough. You can use sysfs or procfs both are simple interface and yet powerful

To ensure module load use "request_module" to load the module from your module as mentioned below If you don't want to load from user-space program.

```
int your_module_init (void)
{
        request_module("<module_name>");

        return 0;
}
```

Or In case of modprobe create inter-depedancy between modules in such a way the driver module will loaded first.

Comment: Can `request_module` also be used for drivers that are compiled into the kernel? Or only for modules (as the name suggests)

Comment: request_module uses /sbin/modprobe internally to load the module. All you need is modules.dep to be update to date. Checkout proc entry /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe